# How to assign values for one column of the attribute table on QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

The table is below.

[image: The table]

Then I want to assign 3 values:

[43.8,
   39.0,
   25.9]

to the X field by row.

What should I do? If there are thousands of rows in the table, can I just paste them just like in Excel?

The version of my QGIS is 3.12.0

Comment: If they Excel file has a matching ID column, and the join is 1:1, you should bring the excel file into QGIS, join it to the shapefile, then use the field calculator to populate a new field with the joined field from excel.

Comment: @DPSSpatial You're right! The table join is a way. But I found an easier method: Field Expression. Use the expression for X field: `array(43.8, 39.0, 25.9)[$id-1]`, and this is demo: [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/GgC2MLo)

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing that...